# How can i get the exe path of the foreground window

Tags: c#, window, foreground

I would like to get the executable file´s path of the active foreground window.

I already have the handler of the foreground window:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
IntPtr handlerAppActual = GetForegroundWindow();
```

And i would like to get the path of it´s executable file, like a shortcut. (ex: C:\application\application.exe)

Why do i need this??
To use it later to automatically execute the application with a call of its process, like this:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @parametros[0];
process.Start();
```

Where "parametros[0]" is the path of the file.

I´m asking for the path of the foreground window´s application, but if you know any other way to do what i need (get the main process of the foreground application to execute it later), i would be please to hear it.

Thanks and salutes!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(VS.85).aspx) to get the process Id, use [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320(VS.85).aspx) to get a process handle from the process Id and then the use the psapi method [GetProcessImageFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683217(VS.85).aspx) on the handle to get the path to the executable.

Or (based on Frank's answer), once you have the Process Id, you can use `Process.GetProcessById(pid)` and then use `MainModule.FileName` property of the `Process` object instance. This way you only need to p/invoke `GetWindowThreadProcessId` and not even use OpenProcess/GetProcessImageFileName.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.process(VS.80).aspx) class. You can use its `MainWindowHandle` property to ask for a process' window handle and compare that to the handle of the window you acquired.

To get a list of all available processes running on your system use the `Process.GetProcesses ()`

If you have the matching process object use the Process.MainModule.FileName property to get the executable file path.

Comment: It is not necessary for the MainWindowHandle to be same as the handle returned by GetForeGroundWindow, even for the same process.