# Identify which executable is throwing a runtime error

Tags: winapi, win32-process

I have a program that is throwing a run-time error dialog. Is there a way to programmatically detect which executable is the parent of this dialog box from another process?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265647/how-can-i-get-the-exe-path-of-the-foreground-window/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The code would be something like this (error checking omitted):

```
HWND hWindow = FindWindow( NULL, windowName );
DWORD processId;
GetWindowTheadProcessId( hWindow, &processId );
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, processId );
GetModuleFileNameEx( hProcess, NULL, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE );
```

The GetProcessImageFileName() function is preferrable to GetModuleFileNameEx() if you aren't concerned with older platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Update: You can get a process name from a window handle using [GetWindowModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633517(VS.85).aspx)

To find the find handle, you could [get the DesktopWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633504(VS.85).aspx) and then enumerate the ones until you find the one with the error message.

Comment: Sorry couldn't get either of those to work :( - GetWindowModuleFileName & GetModuleFileName Works Only with the Calling Process on 2000, XP and Vista. See http://support.microsoft.com/?id=228469.